# Swap two integers without using a third variable

Tags: vb.net, algorithm

I have an assignment in which I need to swap two integers without using third variable.
I'm not sure how to do this. How would I code this?

Comment: Try explaining it to us in a better way and maybe that will put you on the right track.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, it's possible:

```
Dim var1 = 1
Dim var2 = 2
var1 = var1 + var2
var2 = var1 - var2
var1 = var1 - var2
```

But why do you need it? The code becomes abstruse.

Answer (score 7):

Lets assume

```
a = 10; 
b = 20; 

a = a + b; // a = 30

b = a - b; // b = 10
a = a - b; // a = 20
```

Values swapped.

Answer (score 5):

Read up on the "[xor swap algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm)."

You can find an answer here:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0040__Data-Type/Swaptwointegerswithoutusingathird.htm

```
firstValue = firstValue Xor secondValue
secondValue = firstValue Xor secondValue
firstValue = firstValue Xor secondValue
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 Dim a As Integer
 Dim b As Integer
 a= 1
 b= 2

 a = a Xor b
 b = a Xor b
 a = a Xor b
```

Answer (score 2):

To swap two numeric variables do like this

```
a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
```

OR

```
a = a xor b;
b = a xor b;
a = a xor b;
```

where a and b are variables to be swapped

Comment: To swap two *numeric* variables

Answer (score 1):

theoretically 3 ways

```
a = 4 , b = 5
```

**1. Using XOR**

```
a = a XOR b = 4 XOR 5 = 9     
b = a XOR b = 9 XOR 5 = 4
a = a XOR b = 9 XOR 4 = 5
```

**2. Using +,-**

```
a = a+b = 4+5 = 9     // should not overflow
b = a-b = 9-5 = 4
a = a-b = 9-4 = 5
```

**3. Using *,/**

```
a = a*b = 4*5 = 20    // should not overflow
b = a/b = 20/5 = 4    // should not overflow and should not be irrational number
a = a/b = 20/4 = 5    // should not overflow and should not be irrational number
```

Answer (score 0):

The Xor or a+b algorithms above work and are the best way to do this, but just an example of a weird way to do it.  Still not sure why you would want to do this.  Just build a function that you supply two values ByRef and have it do the standard swap method.

```
Dim newList as New List(Of Integer)
newList.Add firstvalue
newList.Add secondValue
newList.Reverse
secondValue = newList.Item(0)
firstValue = newList.Item(1)
```

Comment: Good idea, although `newList` might be considered as third variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Take two text boxes and a command box.In command box type this code.  
    text1.text=val(text1.text) + val(text2.text)      
    text2.text=val(text1.text) - val(text2.text)  
    text1.text=val(text1.text) - val(text2.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check link written for you](http://javaexplorer03.blogspot.in/2016/02/swapping-of-two-numbers-without-using.html)

**Approach#1.**

Addition and Subtraction Method

```
Integer a, b
read a and b
a= a+b;
b=a-b;
a=a-b;
```

**Problem:**

Incorrect result when sum of numbers will exceed the Integer range.

**Approach#2.**

Multiplication and Division Method

```
Integer a, b
read a and b
a=a*b;
b=a/b;
a=a/b;
```

**Problems:**

1. If the value of a*b exceeds the range of integer.
2. If the value of a or b is zero then it will give wrong results.

**Approach#3.**

XOR Method

```
Integer a , b
read a and b
a=a^b;
b=a^b;
a=a^b;
```

**Best approach to solve this problem without any pitfalls.**